# Add axis labels in code project wpf radar control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, radar-chart

This is the link of codeproject wpf radar control: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/446888/Custom-Spider-or-Radar-Chart-Control

This is an awesome control and I want to use it in my application. But it shows only minimum and maximum value as axis labels.

How can I draw all possible axis labels in the chart?

Comment: You'd probably be better off contacting the author if you haven't done so already.

Comment: I have added a comment there, but no one is answering. So I have posted here in a belief that some one may help.

Comment: No one here will do your work for you... *you* need to make an effort. I suggest that you attempt to [replace the default `ControlTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084(v=vs.110).aspx) of the control and if you get stuck, then return here with your attempt.

Comment: I saw the code and did some changes to improve the UI. But there is nothing I can do for axis labels, completely blank from where to start.